# chrome devtools edit css class

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

The devtools seem to only allow for direct element css edits. All the classes are grayed out and the content cannot be changed. Is this expected behavior. I would need to change the style of a class used in a list. Changing css for each individual list item seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the whole class properties by Chrome DevTools.
Just write the Class name.
  by Clicking **Plus Sign** you can write the name of the class or add new class.